# ngx-socket-io fromEvent not working in angular

Tags: angular, socket.io

I'm trying to get event message from socket.io in Angular. I can see the messages in Chrome dev tools so I think my server is working fine. My Angular code for getting the messages is not working. I subscribed to OnFetchOrders() in my component and I want to print the data to console. But Nothing within my subscription is run.
My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
    constructor(private socket: Socket) {
    }

    // listen event
    OnFetchOrders() {
        return this.socket.fromEvent('order_event').pipe(map((data: any) => {
            console.log('ssssss')
            return data.msg;
        }));
    }
}
```

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketService } from 'src/app/services/socket.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-list',
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    

    constructor(
        private socketService: SocketService,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.socketService.OnFetchOrders().subscribe((data: any) => console.log(data))
    }

}
```

My module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/comman/header/header.component';
import { ListComponent } from './components/pages/movies/list/list.component';
import { FormComponent } from './components/pages/movies/form/form.component';

import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';   

const config: SocketIoConfig = {
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/',
    options: {
        transports: ['websocket']
    }
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        ListComponent,
        FormComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
        ModalModule.forRoot(),  
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule 
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```